# How best to add this Action Helper path in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have written a custom ACL class as an Action Helper.  The class name is Controller_Helper_Acl, and is located in the file applications/controllers/helpers/acl.php.  My problem is that my application is having difficulty locating the file.

I want to use the Action Helper Event Hooks, so I need to instantiate the class early.  In my bootstrap.php I tried the Helper Broker's addPath() method, but that doesn't work when I use the new keyword.  (Presumaly it just tells the broker where to find the files when the class is called on demand).

If I put a require_once in the bootstrap, then use the new keyword to instantiate Controllers_Helpers_Acl, it works fine, but I don't think this is a workable solution (since I will have many Action Helpers in the directory).

I tried adding a path to the Autoloader with $loader->registerNamespace('Controllers_Helpers_'), and pluralizing the class name, however file is still not found.  (Perhaps I have the wrong syntax?)

How do others solve this problem?  I suspect that it's my inexperience with Autoloader that's the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file should be located at library/custmname/controller/helper/acl.php, class name should be Customname_Controller_Helper_Acl, to get access to it you need to register the namespace Customname at bootstrap either thru application.ini or hardcoded in index.php or Bootstrap.php, i would recomend using application.ini tough ( add this line `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Customname_"` . There are a big number of examples on how you can achive this ...

Answer (score 4):

You can also specify your Action Helper path in the **application.ini**:

`resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.My_Controller_Action_Helper = "My/Controller/Action/Helper"`

Comment: I want to add Action helpers from path Application_Controller_Helper
but it is generating exception of plugin name not found...
I am using
`resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Application_Controller_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers/helpers"`

Answer (score 3):

You could specify this path in your Bootstrap.php as follows:

```
  protected function _initAutoload() {
        $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

        $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
                    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
                    'namespace' => ''
        );

        $resourceLoader->addResourceType('controller', 'controllers/helpers/', 'Controller_Helper_');

        $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);
  }
```

Hope this helps.